# WYSIWYG HTML editor for Linux with ability to sort tables

Tags: linux, html-editor, wysiwyg

I need an WYSIWYG HTML editor for Linux with the ability to sort tables.

[KompoZer](http://kompozer.net/) does **not** have table sorting, otherwise it would be perfect for my needs.

[Libre Office Writer](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/writer/) **does** have HTML table sorting, but Writer adds a bunch of junk to my clean HTML and it also doesn't let me directly edit the HTML source.

What app is similar to KompoZer, but has the ability to sort an HTML table like Writer?

Alternatively (or in addition) what app is similar to KompoZer but has the ability to run JavaScript (not just edit, but to actually execute it)?

Example of a table (partial):

```
<table class="items">
  <thead>
    <tr class="top-labels">
      <th class="empty">&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item">
      <td class="product-photo-cell"> <a href="http://example.com/item1">
    <img
    src="http://cdn.example.com/350_thumb.jpeg"> </a> </td>
      <td class="product-title-cell"> <a href="http://example.com/item1">Super
    Duper Item</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Take a look at Brackets (http://brackets.io/?lang=en), it's more geared towards your alternative point (runs HTML/CSS/JS 'live'). If you're on Fedora there's a Git repo here: https://github.com/jgillich/brackets-rpm